I need the solution for Spurious Dragon in constructor arguments in Solidity
I wrote 5 contracts modulating the whole operation of bonds of fixed income. I created #1- the storage of data, #2- the pool of investment with USDC, #3- the contract to issue, redeem and amortization, #4- the  contract to deposit the payment by the issuers, and #5- the environment to negotiate the bonds in secundary market.
The contract #5 is returning an error of Spurious Dragon because the size of the bytes is too big, and it happens for the arguments that I wrote of another contract which the #5 is having to call.
I reached the limit of bytes. Now, how can I fix it?

I suggest to try some of the recommendations given in the related question. Enable optimization flag for solc, remove unnecessary functions, etc. If everything fails you can try splitting the contract into several libraries and use delegatecall to call them.
